# Set select value in gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

**Controller:**

```
     def abbrev = [:]
        abbrev.put(1,"I")
        abbrev.put(2,"II")
        abbrev.put(3,"III")
        abbrev.put(4,"IV")
        List<Expando> abbreviations = abbrev.collect{
          abbreviation -> Expando.newInstance(key:abbreviation.key,value:abbreviation.value)
        }

            def row = [:]
            def programRows = [ ]

    somelist.each {
              item -> row = [key1:value1, key2,value2 ]
                programRows << row
            }

[abbreviations:abbreviations, programRows:programRows ]
```

I iterate through programRows so i get a map ( programRow ).
 the map value1 is equivalent to a key in abbreviations ( List of Expandos )  so i want to set the select value based on this: i commented the option value so you can understand what value i want to assign.

**View gsp:**

```
    <g:each in="${programRows}" var="programRow">
   <g:select name="abbrevs" from="${abbreviations}" optionValue="//programRow.get('key1')//" optionKey="key" class="vfuCourseAbbreviations"/>
```

How can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put your code so:

```
def someAction(){
  def abbreviations = [ 'I', 'II', 'III', 'IV' ]
  def programRows = somelist.collect {
    [ key1:value1, key2:value2 ] // as "value1" you have to pass the index in "abbreviations"
  }
  [ abbreviations:abbreviations, programRows:programRows ]
}
```

the GSP:

```
<g:each in="${programRows}" var="programRow">     
  <select name="abbrevs">
    <g:each in="${abbreviations}" var="abbr" status="i">
      <option value="${i}" ${i == programRow.key1 ? 'selected' : ''}>${abbr}</option>
    </g:each>
  </select>     
</g:each>
```

Comment: i tried this and i get this error: No signature of method: groovy.util.Expando.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1] .. 1 is equivalent to key1

Comment: according to your code `programRow` must be an instance of a Map, not an Expando. check it's type

Comment: programRow is instance of Map and "abbrevs" is list of Expando

Comment: is the code that is throwing exception exactly the same as you posted here? or have you "simplified" it?

Comment: its simplified ! but the same structure and variables!

Comment: btw, what's the reason to use expando here?

Comment: i used LinkedHashMap first and it didn't work to set value to the select as the select items were instances of LinkedHashMap! i was getting an error that the value is not property of class LinkedHashMap! the doc talks about  that: optionValue (optional) -  Setting this allows the value to be a bean property of each element in the list.

Comment: i want "abbr" to be matched with equivalent value of "programRow.key1" not a counter .. the code doesn't seem to do this! l( if programRow.key1 = 5 then abbr should be V )

Comment: add 1: `<option value="${i+1}" ${i+1 == programRow.key1 ? 'selected' : ''}>${abbr}</option>`, as the counter starts at 0

Comment: Great! can u explain a bit about 'selected' what does it actually imply? and one last question i was using optionKey to use it in a script onChange event! what attribute now can substitute it? ( i+1) should be the key

Comment: `selected` or `selected="true"` is the HTML-attribute telling the browser engine what option to select by default. You shouldn't substitute anything for your onChange event, the generated HTML-code remains the same

Comment: i meant instead of optionKey in g:select ! as i use the key onChange event of the select!

Comment: i presume the value attribute of the option tag is the "val" i get in my script!?

Comment: I think so... it depends on the JS-library you are using.

Comment: i just had to use id for the select ! it didn't work with the name as for g:select! Thanks for your help